# How to change headers in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problem to modify the column headers to my desired naming. This is my table:

```
st_name  st_id  st_num
Alex      112   1113
Alice     110   1132
```

Expected output:

```
Name      ID    Number
Alex      112   1113
Alice     110   1132
```

How to rename the headers as shown in the expected output table.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

there are several variants of how to achieve what you need

Please note that example based on used range `"A1:C1"`

1 Variant

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "ID"
Cells(1, 3).Value = "Number"
```

2 variant

```
Cells(1, "A").Value = "Name"
Cells(1, "B").Value = "ID"
Cells(1, "C").Value = "Number"
```

3 Variant

```
Range("A1").Value = "Name"
Range("B1").Value = "ID"
Range("C1").Value = "Number"
```

**4 Variant**

```
[A1].Value = "Name"
[B1].Value = "ID"
[C1].Value = "Number"
```

5 Variant, as alternative in case when range goes one after another

```
[A1:C1].Value = Split("Name ID Number")
```

or

```
Range("A1:C1").Value = Split("Name;ID;Number",";")
```

or

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Value = Split("Name ID Number")
```

or

```
Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(1, "C")).Value = Split("Name ID Number")
```

or

```
[A1:C1].Value = Split("Name ID Number")
```

... and so on ... depending on task required to be achieved

Answer (score 6):

In a macro, use the following:

```
Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1").value = "Name"
Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("A2").value = "ID"
Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("A3").value = "Number"
```

Change argument to Worksheets to match the name of the worksheet the change is being made on.  If those are not the first three columns you will need to change the cell reference in the Range method's argument.